# Quotient of M(2,C) by the conjugate action of GL(2,C)

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I am stuck trying to find an explicit subset S of M2(C) which maps bijectively to the set of all orbits of this action.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When are two matrices $A$ and $B$ in $M(n,\Bbb C)$ similar (i.e., there exists $X\in GL(n,\Bbb C)$ such that $AX=XB$)?

Comment: Do you know of any "canonical form" results?